# The best approach to modulize a business logic on Angular?

Tags: angular, laravel, module

I have an application that I use Angular 7 for frontend and Laravel 5.6 for the backend, I know that angular work with modules but is not the kind of module I'm asking, example:

I have an app for a restaurant and have 3 business logic modules like this :

- PDV
- Web Delivery
- Digital Menu

When my client wants to buy the software, he must choose the modules that he wants on the app and what he chooses, automatic my app will show all the options and logic from the system for the module that he chooses, and if don't want he can "uninstall" the module like a PLUGIN.

How is the best practice to make such a thing? I searching for all the internet but only finds modules like services, auth and etc. Not like what I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to implement permission/access based modules. You can define the modules in the router level I guess.
After that, you might need to create access permissions for each modules (say it might be a configuration JSON/etc). Implement Permission logics in the router level (Using AuthGuards).
Each user should have a role (say, collection of permission). The restrictions to modules should work based on this. (unrestricted access to certain modules leads to 404- can be configured using AuthGuards again)